# IIS 7 compression

Tags: iis-7

I know that IIS allows you to compress the files being server. Any idea what the compression ratio is?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compression always depends heavily on what you're compressing. An HTML file will shrink considerably more than a JPEG file, for instance.

Furthermore, both the server and the web browser must support a compression method in order for this compression method to be used in a HTTP transfer. **gzip** and **deflate** are the most common (see [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression)). The compression ratio depends on which method is used and also the actual data being compressed.

Comment: I am only serving aspx pages with no graphics.

Comment: Probably "pretty good", then.  Yes, I know that's vague.  It will depend heavily on your specific site.  Just try it out!